# Is it inappropriate to visit a medieval era tomb on vrat day?

Tags: shiva, rituals, vrata

Planning to visit a historical monument which is basically grand tomb of a Mughal emperor.There are graves of many unknown medieval era people too on that site. In Hinduism, there are restrictions on visiting cemeteries and my mother has vrat of Lord Shiva on Monday so will it be inappropriate for her to visit that too on a day of vrat?